# login screen is showed but i want to show profile page with help of async storage

Tags: react-native

```
if(userLoggedin) {  

console.log(userLoggedin);
navigation.replace('DrawerNavigationRoutes');
return ( <View>
 
  <Text> hello </Text>
  </View>)
 }
 else{
 console.log('login screen');
 console.log(userLoggedin);
 return (
  <View>
 
  <Text> Login screen </Text>
  </View>) )
```

login screen is showing after delaying it goes off and take to profile page.

What to do how my user reach profile page if once is user logged in.

```
  const response = await fetch(
  'http://3.108.170.236/erp/apis/login_otp.php',
  requestOptions,
);
//const response1 = await fetch('https://webhook.site/4326abbc-7ec9- 
 41d0-b967-ad888f79c33a', requestOptions);
console.log('Otp fetched');

 const json_data = await response.json();
 console.log(json_data);

    const userdetails= await AsyncStorage.getItem("Otp_details");
   const details = JSON.parse(userdetails);
   const otp_valued = details[0].otp_value; 
   const student_idd = details[0].student_id; 
   setMyotp_value('123');
   setMyotp_value(otp_valued);
  setMystudent_id(student_idd);                             
  console.log(myotp_value);
  console.log(userOtp);

   if(myotp_value==userOtp){
   console.log('OTP verified');
   navigation.replace('DrawerNavigationRoutes');
   return null;
   } 
   else
   {
   console.log('otp mismatched');
   }
```

help to get the value i am not geting the otp_value for first time when
touch second time data is compared with the asyncstorage.

///////////////////////// getting data //////////////////////////////

```
 try {
   let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Otp_details');
   if (value != null)
   {
      // do something 
      console.log('User mobile Otp verified');
      setUserLoggedin(true);
    //  navigation.replace('DrawerNavigationRoutes');
      
   }
   else 
   {

    // LoginScreen;
    // return null;
   }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store login data in **AsyncStorage** after clicking on the login button :=>

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const loginfun = async (userData) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@logData', userData)
  // pass your desired screen here 
}
```

if you want to check saved data you can ...

```
const checkDataFun = async () => {
  const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@logData');
  console.log(data +"......data")
}
```

Comment: please take a look after edited how i am fetching data through async storage.